PowerBI Buttons to Display the Data Hierarchy (two down arrows) are Greyed Out
I have a Power BI matrix report, and even though I am at the highest level (there are two additional levels), the buttons to go down to the lowest level of data are greyed out. I have to press the + sign at each level to see the next level. See the attached picture. Is there a way to publish the matrix report with all the levels visible by default?

I had this same issue today, if you right click one of the + signs and hover on Expand. You will have the option to Expand All.
